# Uniqueness in requestcodes of pending intents in triggering alarms

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, alarm

I have a **hashmap** of (Date, Integer) where **Date** says the time when I should trigger an Alarm and **Integer** says for how many days I should repeat the Alarm at that time.

Here, inorder to set multiple alarms using android alarm manager it was said that I should set pending intents with unique request code.

My issue is saying for Example:

```
My hashmap values-
9:00 AM - 4 days
3:00 PM - 7 days
```

As of my understanding now I should have total (4+7=)11 pending intents to be set.
now in order to set these alarms, I should have 11 unique request codes..if there are plenty of alarms and the day number increases there are plenty of pending intents to be set where uniqueness is a question mark!

Is that we should generate unique ones or are we having any best solution?

As I'm learning this concept please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Let's work with an example, we have two things to schedule

- A one time alarm
- An alarm for the next 5 days

What you will need is two `PendingIntent`s, one for each.

The one for the one time thing is clear i suppose, you use `AlarmManager#set()` and you supply a `PendingIntent` with a unique id.

The other one, you will need to use `AlarmManager#setRepeating()` and pass in the interval as (milliseconds in a day) assuming you want the alarm to be at same time each day, and this one will one another unique ID.

You end up only needing 2 uniques IDs in total.

For a recurring event, you need one ID, you don't need an ID for each recurrence.

Here is the trick, I am not aware of an API that allows you to restrict a `repeating` alarm for number of days. So basically whenever your `PendingIntent` fires, you need to check if this is the last day it should be fired, and if it is, you can use `AlarmManager#cancel()` to do that.

First idea that comes to mind is calculate the end time of that event, and check every time the intent is fire if you are passed that time or not.

Code example:

```
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),uniqueid, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
long alarmTimeInMillis = ..; // your own value here
long oneDayInterval = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; // 24 hours in millis
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTimeInMillis,
        oneDayInterval, alarmIntent);
```

Also please refer back to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) to determine which method best fits the accuracy your require.

Comment: pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),uniqueid, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT).....alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, predefinedTrigger.getTime(),five_min_time, pi);  here we have one uniqueid that is in pending intent as you said...can u tell me how could i set another uniqueid for everyday..I got stuck there!

Comment: Updated answer, please take a look

Comment: alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmTimeInMillis,
        oneDayInterval, alarmIntent); in my application I have (delay, skip options)such that, say, for eg, I would like to repeat for 5 days continuously then I guess when I cancel(skip) the alarm then the pending intent gets canceled for remaining days as well!

Comment: Have a look at the answer again, you can't limit "repeating" alarm to days, you say that it will run once a day, and it will run forever, but at the fifth day you decide that you no longer need this alarm and you cancel it's pending intent, is that concept not clear, or how you determine that it is the last day is the part that is not clear?

Comment: Okay then...I will let you know what is troubling me! whenever an alarm fires I have a skip option.in that when I skip the alarm I'm internally canceling that pending intent ...as of the discussion should i cancel the ringtone or should i cancel the alarm

Comment: That depends on what "skip" means in your app, if it means I want to cancel the alarm for the rest of days as well, cancel the alarm, if it means only skip the one recurrence that I am seeing now but show me for the rest of the days, then only dismiss notification or ringtone for current alarm and don't cancel the alarm pending intent.

Comment: Yes...I have a delay option as well.when a user clicks delay I am delaying it lets say it is 5 min. in this case I am wondering how could I handle it with that setRepeating